# how to influence the one element of the plurality of dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

http://jsfiddle.net/SergeyKozlov/tewyg2js/3/

I use dynamic insertion HTML code using button events:

```
$("#NewItemImg").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    itemCount++;

    var element = $("\
                    <div class=\"portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all\">\
                        <div class=\"portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all\">img " + itemCount + "\
                            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick portlet-close'></span>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class=\"portlet-content\">\
                            <div class=\"form-group\">\
                                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"article[body][][img]\" id=\"ImageURL\" placeholder=\"Image URL\">\
                            </div>\
                            <button id=\"SetImageURL\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Submit</button>\
                            <img id=\"PanelNewImageURL\" src=\"http://imgde.me/508f93cfb59b5.jpg\" alt=\"2014-12-10T18:04:41.762Z\" title=\"2014-12-10T18:04:41.762Z\" onerror=\"imgError(this);\">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
    ");
```

Then I try to delete the new dynamic element using the following code:

```
$("body").on('click', '.column  .portlet-close', function () {
    $(this).closest( ".portlet" ).remove();
});
```

In this case it works. The problem is how to influence the one element of the plurality of dynamic elements.

```
$("body").on('click', '.column #SetImageURL', function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    // itemCount++;
    $("#PanelNewImageURL").show();
    $("#ImageURL").hide();
});
```

When I use this code, when you acquired any button, and acts only on the first.

Comment: `id` **must** be unique for each element. That's why your code acts only on a first element with given `id`

Comment: *"how to influence the one element of the plurality of dynamic elements"* - How to *what*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because `id` attributes must be unique, but you are using multiple instances of "SetImageURL" as an id.  When jQuery selectors include an id reference in them (as it does here: `on('click', '.column #SetImageURL' . . .`), it acts only on the first matched element with that id, and ignores any other elements that have it, as well.

So, you will either need to figure out a way to make it work with a pure class selector, or a way to make the `id` values unique and include those unique id values in the selector.  I'd go with the first approach . . . though, in either case, you should really make your `id` values unique.   :)

**EDIT:**

Looking at your code again, try this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.column .btn-default', function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    // itemCount++;
    $(this).siblings("img").show();
    $(this).parent().find(".form-control").hide();
});
```